# Solution to fix ajax returning both success and error when it executes php corectly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http

I've got the below ajax code and it works fine. If I send a request the first time, it works fine. If I send the second time, It returns success and error (1 each).

```
$('#eproductForm').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
              $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: $('#eproductForm').attr('action'),
                data: $('#eproductForm').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#eproductModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#eproductForm')[0].reset();
                    save_success();
                    stockList();
                },
                error: function(response){
                    something_wrong();
                }
              });
              return false;
            });
```

Do you have a solution please? share. Thanks

Comment: $('#eproductForm') This shall return a form and not array of forms ?? If Yes then why using array here $('#eproductForm')[0].reset() why not $('#eproductForm').reset() ??

Comment: @ Mukesh Verma It's been working very fine throughout my project

Comment: The first thing I would do is watch in the debugger in your browser to see how many times the form is being submitted to the server. I would not be surprised if the second time you make a request, there are two form submissions instead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you returning false at the end!? I'm hoping

```
                 save_success();
                stockList();
```

this two functions will take you to another place, the thing is when you are returning false maybe the submit aint working correctly so it falls down to the error. Try returning true in success/ false in error, maybe this will fix it. If this doesn't work, try making the Ajax request a promise as in

```
return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {               
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: $('#eproductForm').attr('action'),
            data: $('#eproductForm').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
               resolve(response)
            },
            error: function(response){
                reject(err)
            }
          }); 
}).then((response) => {                    
               $('#eproductModal').modal('hide');
                $('#eproductForm')[0].reset();
                save_success();
                stockList();}).catch((err) => {something_wrong();})
```

this will help you understand how the request is passing through your function. Also, it helps to check your rquest in the chrome developer tools and see what status is returning, so you can deduce at what point is breaking

Comment: @ HectorTinajero your code seems to be working fine, but shows err undefined. If I change reject(err) it still goes back to the initial problem.